# toggleClass multiple divs

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

This code works when I only have one div and I use 'div' in jquery.
It works on the `<p>`.
It even works when I pinpoint with 'div:first-of-type'.

But when I use '#first' or '#second' the only thing that changes is the border.
When I use 'div:last-of-type' everything changes but the background colour.

Why is the code not working properly???

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<p>hello there</p>
<button>button</button>

<style>
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:midnightblue;
}

#second {
    background-color:darkgreen;
}

p {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:aqua;
}

button {
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:brown;
    color:yellow;
}

.black {
    background-color:black;
    border:medium cornsilk dashed;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    color:aliceblue;
}
</style>

     <script>
     $(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('#second').toggleClass('black');
        }); 
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: do you have multiple divs with the same id

Comment: can you recreate the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yxcm7m39/1/ and share the updated link

Comment: `#second` is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.black`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, IDs have more priority than the class name.

```
#second {
    background-color:darkgreen;
}
```

this has the highest priority and:

```
.black {
    background-color:black;
    border:medium cornsilk dashed;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    color:aliceblue;
}
```

has the least one yet the properties which are not in the id selector are applied but not the `background-color`.

You can override it with `#id.class`:

```
 #second.black { /*  <------------------this way */
    background-color:black;
    border:medium cornsilk dashed;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    color:aliceblue;
}
```

You can hack it with `!important` *(Not recommended though)*:

```
.black {
    background-color:black !important;
    border:medium cornsilk dashed;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    color:aliceblue;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` statement is usually not recommended. In this OP case, he could use instead: `[id=second]`: https://jsfiddle.net/wccepn5c/  Or better, being more explicit, using `#second:not(.black)`   https://jsfiddle.net/wccepn5c/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff right may be this could also be done: `#id.class`.

Comment: Oh, ya, i just forgot it :)  Just that he could wish to apply `black` class to other elements but ya definitely, it should just add more specificity to specific rule